# If alert windows stack on screen (without being closed), is that a browser bug by specification?

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-5

Recently it happened to me that multiple `window.alert` windows were active, while working with WebSockets. These were debug alert windows called from my program. I was not able to reproduce it since. As far as I know, `alert` is blocking and JavaScript is synchronous, so unless user closes alert window, no code can execute.

Are there exceptions to the rule, allowing multiple alert instances to be called, or was that a bug I should find and report?

Edit: I was just able to cause this using just `window.onresize = function() {alert("Resize!");}`

Comment: The `alert()` mechanism doesn't stop (some) event handling.

Comment: @Pointy Doesn't that mean those events could change some variables in an unexpected way? Does that non-blocking exception apply to `alert` only, or some events simply can execute along with another code?

Comment: The `alert()` mechanism has issues. It's hard to control, it can't be styled, etc. There's really no good reason to use it in production code.

Comment: from what i've seen, firefox lets them stack up, others don't